# HTML5 / JS - Display multiple file input in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using HTML5's wonderful 'multiple' file select feature.

```
<input type="file" id="fileInput" onChange="runTest()" multiple>
```

I would like to display the selected filenames below the input field and make it look pretty with CSS, however...

If I run a test JS function, that 'alerts' me of the input field's value, it only shows one file regardless of me selecting 10.

```
function runTest() {
var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput').value;
alert("You selected: "+fileInput);
}
```

I was doing this for when I had a 'single' file input field and worked okay but now it's 'multiple', it doesn't like it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, it seems the value, or `val()`, returned by the element is the name of only the last file selected. To work around this, it might be wise to use the nature of the multiple-change events:

```
$('input:file[multiple]').change(
    function(){
        $('ul').append($('<li />').text($(this).val()));
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/LZLBn/).

And either output the names to a list (as in the example), or append the latest value to an array, or, possibly, use/create hidden inputs to store the filenames as you feel would best suit your application.

To access the file-names (as well as last modified date, file-size...) you can (tested in Chromium 12/Ubuntu 11.04) use the following:

```
$('input:file[multiple]').change(
    function(e){
        console.log(e.currentTarget.files);
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/LZLBn/1/).

---

**Edited** to make the above slightly more useful and, hopefully, demonstrative:

```
$('input:file[multiple]').change(
    function(e){
        console.log(e.currentTarget.files);
        var numFiles = e.currentTarget.files.length;
            for (i=0;i<numFiles;i++){
                fileSize = parseInt(e.currentTarget.files[i].fileSize, 10)/1024;
                filesize = Math.round(fileSize);
                $('<li />').text(e.currentTarget.files[i].fileName).appendTo($('#output'));
                $('<span />').addClass('filesize').text('(' + filesize + 'kb)').appendTo($('#output li:last'));
            }
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/LZLBn/2/).

The final code-block updated, due to changes in Webkit, Chrome 24 (though possibly from earlier), by [nextgentech](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719264/html5-js-display-multiple-file-input-in-div/7719334#comment20292311_7719334) in comments, below:

```
$('input:file[multiple]').change(
    function(e){
        console.log(e.currentTarget.files);
        var numFiles = e.currentTarget.files.length;
            for (i=0;i<numFiles;i++){
                fileSize = parseInt(e.currentTarget.files[i].size, 10)/1024;
                filesize = Math.round(fileSize);
                $('<li />').text(e.currentTarget.files[i].name).appendTo($('#output'));
                $('<span />').addClass('filesize').text('(' + filesize + 'kb)').appendTo($('#output li:last'));
            }
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dlong500/LZLBn/61/).

Comment: Thanks David, I used this but still didn't manage to get it to produce all files, weird. I have actually just read an article on HTML5 (http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) which if applied, would be much better for me. Without doubt thou', your code actually helped me with another issue I was having elsewhere, so thanks...

Comment: Really? It worked consistently in Chromium, albeit that's no guarantee of other browsers' behaviour. Anyway, I'm glad to have been of (some) help, if I get a chance I'll try and look further into this.

Comment: [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dlong500/LZLBn/61/) to account for Chrome/Chromium changes in file attributes (fileSize is now **size**, fileName is now **name**) as of at least v24 (possibly earlier).

Comment: I can see a potential problem with the above, are the listed file still form submission elements when you re-select new files with the fileuploader?

Comment: it would be nice if you could also put (X) sign to remove some of the selected files.

Answer (score 0):

Set a break point on the alert call and take a look at the contents of the variable fileInput, see if there is another property that contains all of the file names.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent code but object needs to be empty for each change:

```
$('input:file[multiple]').change(
function(e){
    $('#output').empty();
    console.log(e.currentTarget.files);
    var numFiles = e.currentTarget.files.length;
        for (i=0;i<numFiles;i++){
            fileSize = parseInt(e.currentTarget.files[i].fileSize, 10)/1024;
            filesize = Math.round(fileSize);
            $('<li />').text(e.currentTarget.files[i].fileName).appendTo($('#output'));
            $('<span />').addClass('filesize').text('(' + filesize + 'kb)').appendTo($('#output li:last'));
        }
});
```

Thank you David...

Comment: how to remove a selected file?